# Is it possible to get the public key of a bitcoin address I do not have the private keys for with the standard client?

Tags: public-key

It is possible to get it from here:
https://blockchain.info/de/q/pubkeyaddr
https://blockchain.info/q

Is it possible with the standard client? How?

I am aware that the blockchain only contains the pubkey after a tx from that address.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is impossible to compute the public key of an address, as the address is computed from the hash of the public key. You can retrieve the public key from address with the reference client using the `validateaddress` RPC call (or in the debug window of Bitcoin-Qt), but that simply fetches it from the wallet, and only works if the address belongs to you.

Update: you need to use `getaddressinfo` now instead of `validateaddress`.

Comment: I would like to encrypt messages by abusing bitcoin/namecoin signing keys as encryption keys. see: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=145098    I am aware there might be peripheral risks to using the same keys for signing and encryption.

Comment: To elaborate, a public key is 33 bytes long, whereas an address is a 20-byte hash of the public key. Because the information is smaller, therefore it is impossible to compute the correct public key from an address.

Comment: don't i need the full pub key for an address i do NOT own when creating a new multisig address with "addmultisigaddress"?

Comment: It IS possible to recover the public key from the signature though (so you can recover the public key of an address already seen on the blockchain), see the answer below.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't it be possible to lookup int he blockchain and see if that person spent from that address and then get the public key used to sign the transaction?

Comment: @PieterWuille : but payment transactions are performed to a pubkey… Right ?

Comment: What are "payment transactions"?

Comment: @user2284570 Bitcoin transactions have an input and output address and are normally sent to a "pubkey hash", not a "pubkey". A bitcoin address is just a pubkey hash with a header and checksum bytes appended then encoded with base58checked. So you can go from a bitcoin address to a pubkey hash without a problem.

Answer (score 14):

To be honest, it IS possible, but you need a signature made by that address. From that point, you can get the public key.

See this piece of code: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-message/blob/master/index.js#L57

Answer (score 12):

It is impossible.  Given an ECDSA (compressed 65Bytes or not 33Bytes) public-key K, a Bitcoin
address is generated using the cryptographic hash functions SHA-256 and RIPEMD-160.
The public-key is hashed twice: HASH160 = RIPEMD-160(SHA-256(K)). The Bitcoin address is computed directly from this HASH160 value as

```
base58(0x00 || HASH160 || bSHA-256(SHA-256(0x00 || HASH160))/2224c). "||=concatenation"
```

[image]

so it is impossible to reverse the hash to get the public key.

Comment: @PieterWuille : but payment transactions are performed to a pubkey… Right ?

Comment: it depends on the transaction type

Comment: I wrote this in the sense this is a requirement.

Comment: the pub key is shared with the network so no need to reverse an address to get the pubkey

Comment: @user2284570 What is a "payment transaction"?

Comment: @PieterWuille a transaction which bear value with a receipient which is not a miner.

Comment: In that case, no; there are almost no pay-to-pubkey outputs at all.

Comment: @BadrBellaj -- you wrote: "the pub key is shared with the network so no need to reverse an address to get the pubkey" -- So can the public key be retrieved from the network?

Comment: I just started to learn bitcoin today. By Socratic deduction, I read that a hash represents on behalf of the public key in order to hide the public key. Therefore, I conclude that the public key can never be retrieved from its hash.