# How to confirm that given bitcoin address is generated by given public key?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, blockchain-wallet-app, blockcypher

I have 10s of private and public keys associated with 10s of different addresses.

Now I have a test-net btc address "**mfoxBS2TpoiUWrEV3sZopoEB6Pi2d7TE9N**".

What operations can I perform to find the appropriate **Public Key** associated with **given address**?

**UPDATE**
I am not trying to find out reverse scenario of fetching a public key from address.

As I already have bunch of public keys. One of them have created the given address. And I just want to figure out which one is it from the whole bunch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the public key of a bitcoin address I do not have the private keys for with the standard client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11604/is-it-possible-to-get-the-public-key-of-a-bitcoin-address-i-do-not-have-the-priv)

Comment: it's not duplicate. updated my question description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a step-by-step guide [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses#How_to_create_Bitcoin_Address) and you can also test it on [this](https://gobittest.appspot.com/Address) site.

You can also use [this](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools) python library.

```
import os
os.environ['CRYPTOTOOLS_NETWORK'] = 'test'

from btctools import PublicKey

>>> pub = Publickey.from_hex('yourpubkeyhere')
>>> pub.to_address('P2PKH')
'mp9CpH3h25m7FZqsPBf2UfU9Gm4u41j9Eg'
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this check by Java program or using Api?

Comment: There is a java library call bitcoinj that might be able to do this. Also there is this: https://bitcore.io/playground/#/address but I wouldn't trust any online service with a private key. It might be good enough for testnet though.

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to derive the address from each public key, and compare it with the address you have.